# GLib-GObject: g_object_replace_qdata error with Weasyprint

Tags: python, gtk, gobject, weasyprint

I am trying to print a simple PDF file using Weasyprint following [this simple tutorial](https://dev.to/bowmanjd/python-pdf-generation-from-html-with-weasyprint-538h)

I run this command: 
`python weasyprintdemo.py sample.html sample.pdf`

Inside a folder containing the following files:

```
weasyprintdemo.py
sample.html
sample.css
```

The output of the command is an infinite loop with the following 2 messages:

```
(process:7356): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 11:23:32.010: g_object_replace_qdata: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
(process:7356): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 11:23:32.010: g_object_get_qdata: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
```

The expected **sample.pdf** is not generated.

The content of weasyprintdemo.py, sample.html and sample.css can be found [here](https://github.com/bowmanjd/pyweasyprintdemo)

I've solved countless problems trying to make this script working but I am stuck on this one for a week now... Any ideas ?

My working environnment :

- Windows 10
- virtualenv 20.13.3
- Python 3.6.8
- Pip 21.3.1
- Weasyprint 54.2
- GTK3 3.24.31 from [here](https://github.com/tschoonj/GTK-for-Windows-Runtime-Environment-Installer/releases)

```
> weasyprint --info 

System: Windows
Machine: AMD64
Version: 10.0.17134
Release: 10

WeasyPrint version: 54.2
Python version: 3.6.8
Pydyf version: 0.1.2
Pango version: 15003
```

The GTK is installed in **C:\GTK3** and **C:\GTK3\bin** is at the top of my Path.

Comment: Those assertion failures indicate that this is a bug in weasyprint, which should be reported on their bug tracker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked when I downgraded Weasyprint and the GTK to older version.

New working version:

- Python 3.9.5
- Pip 21.3.1
- Weasyprint 52
- GTK3 3.24.13-2019-12-19